# What is the relationship between Jupyter kernels and anaconda env?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I'm new to python and I choose anaconda to start.
Soon, I have a question...
What is the relationship between Jupyter kernels and anaconda env?
I have looked up the official documents of Jupyter, but I found only the
architecture of Jupyter, Ipython...etc.

[The Jupyter Notebook Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HufMi.jpg)
[Messaging in IPython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2xA2.jpg)

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

as what i understand, for each anaconda env, you can choose a specific python version, and also install a jupyter kernal to work inside this anaconda env. so you can think that the python, jupyter kernal and other packages inside this anaconda env are all parallel to each other. The anaconda env is just a container for all of above mentioned.

Comment: So can different kernals(say python3.7 and 3.8) in the same anaconda env shares the same packages(in anaconda env)?

Comment: you said  python, jupyter kernal and other packages inside this anaconda env are all parallel to each other, it means that they are actually "copied" inside the env, right?

Comment: dont think in one env, you can have different python version, if you need that, than it is better to use different envs.

Comment: yes, they are copied, you can find the individual folders in the anaconda folders. @shauchen